# Is RewriteEngineOn used only once in httpd.conf or can it be used multiple times?

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I read that a directory block in httpd.conf is like a .htaccess file. Does that mean that RewriteEngineOn can be used multiple times within httpd.conf? I'm assuming that it can be but it must be placed within directory blocks. Can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean that RewriteEngineOn can be used multiple times within httpd.conf?

Yes, that's fine.

> I'm assuming that it can be but it must be placed within directory blocks.

No, it's valid in any configuration context, and will inherit down to other contexts - so if you have it enabled at the `<VirtualHost>`, you don't need it within `<Directory>` blocks inside that vhost.  The one exception is that it doesn't inherit from the server configuration down into `<VirtualHost>` (consistency in how configuration applies isn't exactly one of Apache's strengths).